# "global" keyword does not work from within drush script

Tags: 7, drush

I have the following script:

```
<?php 

$GLOBALS['foo1'] = "foobar1";
function g1() {
    echo "g1 " . $GLOBALS['foo1'] . "\n";
}

$foo2 = "foobar2";
function g2() {
    global $foo2;
    echo "g2 " . $foo2 . "\n";
}

g1();
g2();
```

Running it on the browser gives me:

```
g1 foobar1
g2 foobar2
```

Running it via `drush scr example.php` gives me:

```
g1 foobar1
g2
```

Any idea why the `global` keyword doesn't work when I run the script via drush?

I run this on a D7 site with PHP 5.3.5.

Comment: I haven't checked, but presumably Drush runs this in a non-global scope, so `$foo2 = "foobar2"` is not equivalent to `$GLOBALS['foo2'] = "foobar2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve it I had to add `global $foo;` before declaring `$foo`.

I suppose it relates to this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#98811